# Windows GetTickCount in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, gettickcount

Is it possible go get the current windows TickCount in Ruby?

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi) for example. 
At first, you should install `ffi` gem:

```
gem install ffi
```

And then attach this function:

```
require 'ffi'
module Foo
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib "kernel32.dll"
  ffi_convention :stdcall

  attach_function :get_tick_count, :GetTickCount, [ ], :int
end
puts Foo.get_tick_count #=> 107073812
```

Answer (score 1):

use windows api:

```
require 'Win32API'

t = Win32API.new("kernel32", "GetTickCount", nil, 'L')
t.call()
```

or `Time.now - t.call() / 1000.0` to get a time when machine was booted